# Linkedin share on company page API is not working at all.

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I am using Linking JS SDK and following below example for sharing a post on my company page:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages

I used blow code to share post:

```
// Build the JSON payload containing the content to be shared    
  function onSuccess(response){
    console.log(response);
  }
  function onError(){
    console.log(response);
  }

    var payload = { 
      "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com! http://linkd.in/1FC2PyG", 
      "visibility": { 
        "code": "anyone"
      } 
    };

    var cpnyID = 2414183;

    IN.API.Raw("/companies/" + cpnyID + "/shares?format=json")
      .method("POST")
      .body(JSON.stringify(payload))
      .result(onSuccess)
      .error(onError);
```

in response i am getting:

```
{
"errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Internal service error",
  "requestId": "TZ1QE0M3VP",
  "status": 500,
  "timestamp": 1526892099561
}
```

i have tried with different user and many different company ids, i also tried with fresh user and fresh company pages, but every time "Internal Service Error" is returned from service.

Please Help.

Comment: Its happending when i am sharing on any company page using js sdk, when i am calling from any REST tool(postman), its working and post shared.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue. Could we get any help from LinkedIn dev team?

Comment: The LinkedIn JS SDK is no longer supported (https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates).

>SDKs: Our JavaScript and Mobile Software Development Kits (SDKs) will stop working. Developers will need to migrate to using OAuth 2.0 directly from their apps.

Comment: @ChristopherOu This is also happening to me with Oauth requests in my PHP app. Using the same SDK to post code to my personal page is working as expected however it is not working for the company page.